# Using Cassandra for Message Archive Management (mod_mam) database in Ejabberd 16.09

Tags: cassandra, erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, nosql

I'm trying to use Cassandra for mod_mam in Ejabberd 16.09. Does that version of Ejabberd support Cassandra? If it does, how to configure Ejabberd to use Cassandra?

Also, I found some Erlang-Cassandra driver such as Cqerl, Erlcass, and Erlang-cassandra-cql. Can I use them to connect Ejabberd and Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ejabberd doesn't support Cassandra as a database backend. The only available backends at the moment are: internal (i.e. Mnesia), Riak, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, sqlite and other ODBC compatible databases.
Of course you can use mentioned Erlang drivers, but this will not be very easy to write a new database backend using them: some experience in Erlang and ejabberd is required.

Comment: I still don't understand. If I can perform query like this: `{ok, Result} = cqerl:run_query(Client, "SELECT * FROM users;").` in Cqerl, doesn't that mean that I just have to create `mod_mam_cassandra.erl` just like `mod_mam_sql.erl` in Ejabberd?

Comment: Sure you can do this, I didn't say this is impossible :)